# How to access columns with same names of all dataframes in a list?

Tags: r

As was suggested somewhere in Stackoverflow, to store a number of dataframes, I put them in a list. Now, how can I access particular columns - all with the same name - of all dataframes in that list (to find a maximum)?

```
list[1:25]["colname"]
```

gives `NULL` and

```
list[[1:25]]["colname"]
```

gives 
`"Error in list[[1:25]] : recursive indexing failed at level 3"`,

although I can get one column with

```
list[[1]]["colname"]
```

I also tried `c()`, but didn't work.

I have tried several searches, but couldn't find anything relevant. I'm not really a programmer, just needing that for research. I'm learning R (with Rstudio) on the fly (I have read some tutorials), so it might be that I just don't know the right words to search.

Comment: Use `lapply` with \`[\` a as your function.

Comment: 3 answers and not one comment on any of them?! You might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of SO. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Comment: I apologize to the answerers, I did read about and FAQ, and I know that I should upvote and comment. I had some problems testing the answers with my data at that time, and after a certain amount of time of trying I had to decide to solve my problem manually - after which I totally forgot to come back here. Probably one of the answers could have solved my problem, but because my situation made the problem moot, I can't really say which one would have been the one. Should I upvote all answers for trying, or what is the correct etiquette here?

Comment: Well, I decided to test the answers now that I have time. I still apologize for the delay, but at least I now tried to reply to the answerers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x is your list and Sepal.Length is the column of which you want to take the maximum over all datasets in your list:

```
x <- rep(list(iris),25)


max(unlist(lapply(x,function(df) max(df$Sepal.Length))))
```

If you want the maximum for every dataset in the list:

```
lapply(x,function(df) max(df$Sepal.Length))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!
What does the function(df) do, though? Help does not seem to work for that.

Comment: ...It seems to create (?) a kind of temporary name for the dataframe which can be used to refer to the columns, but what the heck, how does that work?

Comment: Read `?lapply`. The function is applied to each element of the list. Intuitively you could see it as a loop where for each loop `df` is replaced by an element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible way using `sapply` along with `[[`.

```
data <- list(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), 
             data.frame(a = 10:15, b = 40:45))

sapply(data, "[[", "b")
[[1]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[2]]
[1] 40 41 42 43 44 45
```

Comment: That gave me access to the correct columns in the dataframes, so thanks for that, but JT85's answer solved my next problem: how to get max from those.

Answer (score 0):

One of the `apply` family functions will do the trick. Using an anonymous function in this case to operate on each `data.frame` in the list to find the `max` value of the first column...

```
#  Make some reproducible data
set.seed(1)
ll <- replicate( 3 , as.data.frame( matrix( sample( 9 ) , 3 ) ) , simplify = FALSE )
#[[1]]
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  4  3
#2  9  8  5
#3  7  2  6

#[[2]]
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  4  8  5
#2  7  2  3
#3  6  9  1

#[[3]]
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  6  4  2
#2  3  9  5
#3  1  7  8

#  Get max value of each of the first columns - could use a quoted column name here
lapply( ll , function(x) max( x[ , 1 ] ) )
#[[1]]
#[1] 9

#[[2]]
#[1] 7

#[[3]]
#[1] 6
```

Comment: Seems to be essentially the same than JT85's answer - however, the quoted column name does not work, but gives "Error in `[.data.frame`(x, "colname") : undefined columns selected". Why does the $-reference in JT85's work, as does the [,1], but quoted column name does not? I totally don't get R's way of different referencing practices and their differences.

Comment: @RandomMonitor Well we posted at the same time and that answer differed subtly until it was edited which was *after* I had posted my answer (which I think is cleaner anyway). You must be spelling your column name wrong?! e.g. try `lapply( ll , function(x) max( x[ 'V1' ] ) )` from my example. Works just fine?

Comment: (It was not a critique, just an observation.)
It does work with your example, but not with my data. Could it be because one of the dataframes in the list does not have the column that all the others have? If so, then why does $-reference work? It gives a warning "In max(df$colname) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf", but only a warning, not an error, so it still does what I asked it to.